# Google maps geocoder not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am coding an AngularJs 1.x app (too lazy to learn TypeScript).

The first script in my index.html is

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxx"></script>
```

in my controller I have

```
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        Object.keys(companies).forEach(function(key) 
        {
            var companyName = key;
            var comapnyLocation = companies[key];

          console.log('Key : ' + key + ', Value : ' + companies[key])

          geocoder.geocode( { 'address': comapnyLocation}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
              console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
```

When I breakpoint on the line after the decoder declaration, I see that it is an object. I breakpoint both the success & failure branches of the callback & hit only the OK branch. However, by that point, geocoder is not defined.

What am I doing wrongly?

Note: I checked my Google dashboard and I do have the API enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because you are trying to use google maps api **TOO EARLY**

As per the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

> The async attribute lets the browser render the rest of your website while the Maps JavaScript API loads. When the API is ready, it will call the function specified using the callback parameter.

---

Create a javascript function, name it anything, then in your script tag that you use to call google maps api, add in the following parameter:

`&callback=YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME_HERE`

```js
var map, geocode;
var companies = {
Google: '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway in Mountain View'
};

function initMap(){

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
  zoom: 8
});

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


Object.keys(companies).forEach(function(key) 
{
  var companyName = key;
  var comapnyLocation = companies[key];
  console.log('Key : ' + key + ', Value : ' + companies[key])
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': comapnyLocation}, function(results, status) {

  console.log("Results:", results );
      
    if (status == 'OK') {
        console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
});
}
```

```html
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

#### Results

[image]

Comment: `Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",`

Comment: `The reason it's not working is because you are trying to use google maps api TOO EARLY` - I am not so sure about that. If I just hardcode lat long and add markers it's fine. It's only the geodecode that is giving problems

Comment: Apologies for that, seems like i was missing a closing brace(s)... I have tested this by creating my own API key, enabling the GeoCoding API and it works for me, see above the output of the results

Comment: My problem is that this is AngularJs 1.x, so I need to get the data into `$scope` - any idea how? Preferably by callings a controller scope function, but I don't know the syntax. If just a  a global function, how could I gave it set some controller scope data?

Comment: In the end, I solved it by rebasing my code on [this Plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/Dc2NHNbahtMbyc91XfKc/), which lets me use AngularJs 1.x and ngMap. Thanks for your help

Comment: Only a pleasure. Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: Thanks a 1,000,000 - alas, I did not give a complete question, so while your answer helps others, it could never have helped me. Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all, my apologies to @CraigWayne. I am sure that his answer will help others, but since I failed to give full information in my question, he could not have been expected to give ma an answer.

I am coding in AngularJs 1.x, and I am using [NgMap](https://ngmap.github.io/).

So, when Craig suggests waiting foe the map to completely load, I suspect that NgMap's `<map>` directive takes care of that.

What worked for me - although I do not know how - was replacing the declaration of

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

and    `geocoder.geocode( { 'address': comapnyLocation}, function(results, status)` by

```
var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' +  
            comapnyLocation +'&key=XXXX';

$http.get(url)
```

which gives the results that Craig indicated (in `data.results`).

Just leaving this here in case it helps anyone in future.

Comment: @allenhwkim any comments?